# How to restrict the run of a dll only on one computer?

Tags: dll

So my question is simple and probably your answers will tell this is not possible...

Maybe on the first use of the dll file, I should see what is the MAC Address and put a restriction on that base? :)

Comment: This is not possible. However there are likely other options for what you trying to do. Is this some sort of licensing?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to restrict the use of a dll file in Autocad environment for one computer only.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! You could manage a kind of white/black list (of course encrypted) in your DLL and handle the restriction code in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH and then return TRUE or FALSE according to your needs.

Comment: True/false condition can be detected by an attached debugger and later modified to inverse - i.e. run when condition is incorrect. There needs to be a set of actions to disallow debugging and protect the lib.

Comment: Disabling the attachment of a debugger, fight against code status modifications is NOT specific to DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to search for specific technology or language and see what standard approaches do people use for this.

There is a trade off between how difficult it is to set up your product and the defence level. The tougher you make it for the bad guys, the tougher it will become to use your product.

You can use some sort of obfuscation and library encryption, which will work providing your user has a key (or password).